# I can't seem to find my keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout, language, microsoft-surface

I have this 2015 Microsoft Surface Pro 4 that has an AZERTY keyboard but I can't seem to find the correct language on Windows OS. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` "Data" column  shows the languages that I added but none of them is the correct one.

Here's what it looks like :

[image]

The fact that it's an AZERTY keyboard made me think that it's probably french but that wasn't the case. The keys above 1-9 are absolutely not the same as a french keyboard, same thing goes for the '@' key and others. I did try all the french layout variants just in case but none of them was it.

Comment: Run `regedit` and navigate to the key `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`. Which codes do you under the "Data" column?

Comment: This shows the languages that I added but none of them is the correct one.

Comment: Do you mean that the keyboard layout when you got the computer was already incorrect?

Comment: I just formatted the computer and I chose French as the keyboard language but it was incorrect. Now I'm trying to find the correct language that corresponds to the keyboard in the picture above.

Comment: Windows has 13 [variants of French](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php). You could just install them one by one and check.

Comment: Please don't add info in comments. It's much better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1772443/edit) the question as I now did for you. Then all the relevant info is readily available. AZERTY is the French thing - it'd be helpful if you indicated what exactly you expect to see and where, and what exactly you actually do see.

Comment: @harrymc I did and none of them worked.

Comment: This is worrying. Can't you find any sticker or anything on the Surface that can indicate its origin?

Comment: The special characters make it look like a UK keyboard layout, but I can't find anything about a possible UK Azerty one.